# Handling Many to Many

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm stuck trying to model a many to many relationship.  Here's a representative sample of my issue using an e-commerce model:

```
+------------+-------------+----------+------------+
|    date    | customer_id | order_id | address_id |
+------------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 12/1/2019  |           1 |        1 |          1 |
| 12/15/2019 |           2 |        1 |          1 |
| 12/15/2019 |           2 |        2 |          2 |
| 1/1/2020   |           2 |        3 |          1 |
| 1/1/2020   |           1 |        2 |          3 |
| 1/1/2020   |           1 |        3 |          2 |
| 1/2/2020   |           1 |        4 |          1 |
+------------+-------------+----------+------------+
```

- A customer can place many orders.
- A customer can ship to multiple addresses.
- Addresses can have multiple customers.

How would I model a "household" junction/bridging table?  In my data above, customer_id 1 and 2 could possibly be a family or business entity.  What if I wanted to know on a given date, how many orders that household/entity placed, how many customers that household represented and how many locations did they ship to?

I think this is the start of how I build this model, but stuck on writing the bridging query.

```
orders                        addresses
+-------------+----------+    +-------------+------------+
| customer_id | order_id |    | customer_id | address_id |
+-------------+----------+    +-------------+------------+
|           1 |        1 |    |           1 |          1 |
|           1 |        2 |    |           1 |          2 |
|           1 |        3 |    |           1 |          3 |
|           1 |        4 |    |           2 |          1 |
|           2 |        1 |    |           2 |          2 |
|           2 |        2 |    +-------------+------------+
|           2 |        3 |
+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database you want to keep all the similar data in separate tables.  This helps you with making joins later.  I would recommend:
[image]